# Chart only rows with "x"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a Google Sheets with measurements I take daily (the rows), multiple times a day. I have a "before breakfast" column, values are "Yes" or "No". How do I make a chart which shows only the "before breakfast" = "Yes" values.

I already have a chart showing all values for all times and days.

Answer (score 1):

Filter the Column of `Yes`s and `No`s to select only the `Yes`s.